# Retrieve data from WSDL

Tags: node.js, wsdl

I'm trying to retrieve properties like Operation name, method type, request-response parameters etc. from a WSDL file/url through nodejs. I tried using an npm package 'wsdlrdr' which does return the operation name but does not retrieve the parameters the same way if I import the wsdl file in SOAP UI.

Is there a way to retrieve all the elements using nodejs? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [SOAP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) npm package to retrive details from WSDL file/url. It works well with WSDL files